# "In" versus "of", how can I choose between them?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, meaning-in-context, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

In a lot of phrases "in" and "of" seem to have the same meaning, however, after a quick search I found that some sentences are not common; can any one give me a logical explanation as to how to choose between those prepositions??

1- Doctor of Engineering (common) vs Doctor in Engineering (not common)

2- Bachelor of Engineering (common) vs Bachelor of Engineering (not common)

3- Bachelor's degree in Engineering (common) vs Bachelor's degree of Engineering  (not common)

Answer (score 1):

1/2 - **He is** a Doctor/Bachelor of Engineering -"Doctor/Bachelor of Engineering" is a title

But

3- **He has** a Bachelor's degree in Engineering.

3a- **He has** a doctorate in Engineering

Answer (score 0):

[Doctor of Engineering (common) vs Doctor in Engineering (not common)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Doctor+of+Engineering%2CDoctor+in+Engineering&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDoctor%20of%20Engineering%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDoctor%20in%20Engineering%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CDoctor%20of%20Engineering%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDoctor%20in%20Engineering%3B%2Cc0)

[Bachelor of Engineering (common) vs Bachelor of Engineering (not common)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Bachelor+of+Engineering%2CBachelor+in+Engineering&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBachelor%20of%20Engineering%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBachelor%20in%20Engineering%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CBachelor%20of%20Engineering%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBachelor%20in%20Engineering%3B%2Cc0)

[Bachelor's degree in Engineering (common) vs Bachelor's degree of Engineering (not common)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Bachelor%27s+degree+in+Engineering%2CBachelor%27s+degree+of+Engineering&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBachelor%20%27s%20degree%20in%20Engineering%3B%2Cc0)

There is no difference in meaning in the first two cases and in the third "of" is not correct, it is used for the degree for instance, not the disciplines.

[university degree of](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=university+degree+of+*%2Cuniversity+degree+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cuniversity%20degree%20of%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Buniversity%20degree%20of%20Doctor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Buniversity%20degree%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Buniversity%20degree%20of%20Bachelor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Buniversity%20degree%20of%20honours%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Buniversity%20degree%20of%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuniversity%20degree%20in%3B%2Cc0)

In consequence of this, use "in" for the third case. For the first two, as there is an overwhelming majority in favour of "of", you might as well stick to "of" and thus make the majority even stronger and the language simpler. Of course, since there are some people using "in", it is not "forbidden" to use it if you feel it adds something to the meaning.